# Sonata | Custom field in ListMapper

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata

I'm searching in Sonata doc but I can't find if it is possible.

I have an Entity Question with one to many relation with Answer.

In my ListMapper for QuestionAdmin, I would like to do something like :

```
$listMapper
  ->addIdentifier('title')
  ->add('countAnswers', IntegerType::class, array(
     'action', 'getCountAnswers'
        )
  );
```

I know the code below is wtf but
I have no idea if this is possible or how to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just want to display the value in the admin list you could extend you entity with a simple **getAnswersCount** function and reference this field (function) in the admin:

example reference:

**AppBundle\Entity\Questions**

```
public function getAnswersCount() 
{
    return $this->getAnswers()->count();
}
```

**QuestionAdmin**

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('title')
        ->add('answersCount')
    ;
}
```

Comment: Didn't know this was possible. TY lordrhodos

Comment: Can you call a method of a Entity who need a argument? Like "getsAnswersCount($id)" if the entity have internal logic?